# How to cast 9999 as 999999 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please specify a query where I am able to cast 9999 int data to 999999 int data so that my schema has 999999 as the maximum integer value?

Comment: *"Cast `9999` to `999999`"*? That doesn't make sense. Casting a value means changing it's datatype. Also, *why* have you tagged 3 completely different RDBMS?

Comment: Those are two very different values. First of all it's not a cast but a conversion. And second, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`cast()` doesn't have that effect on the values.  I suspect that you simply want `update`:

```
update t
    set col = 999999
    where col = 9999;
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you are trying to do here but in mysql you could cast,concat and then cast again.

```
select cast(concat(cast(9999 as char(5)),'9') as unsigned) nines;

+-------+
| nines |
+-------+
| 99999 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```